# How do I avoid URL globbing with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, url, curl, format, glob

I have a url (slightly modified) like so:

```
https://ssl.site.com/certificate/123/moo.shoo?type=456&domain=$GH$%2fdodo%20[10%3a47%3a11%3a3316]
```

It doesn't work the way I intend it to when passed straight through to PHP cURL because of the brackets.

I managed to run the same URL successfully in the command line like so:

```
curl -g "https://ssl.site.com/certificate/123/moo.shoo?type=456&domain=$GH$%2fdodo%20[10%3a47%3a11%3a3316]"
```

Is there an option (similar to -g, for disabling globbing) that I can use in PHP cURL? If not, how should I encode or format my URL before passing it to PHP cURL?

Comment: This probably needs URLEncoding but only for the values (e.g. the `$GH$%2fdodo%20[10%3a47%3a11%3a3316]`)

Comment: It seems you're not really asking how to encode a URL. You're asking how to disable URL globbing, right?

Comment: You have a point, but they are related. I am asking a general question in the case where globbing disablement is not a feature in php.

Comment: Right. So you're asking how to avoid globbing. Possible answers may include explicitly turning it off or working around it by writing the URL differently. Don't limit your answers to X when you really just want Y.

Comment: In the short term I really want Y... but in the long term I also want X, because Y is only a subset of X... if you know what i mean

Comment: I just noticed you edit my question title. Hmmm. Thanks?

Comment: I see value in this question being more general for the benefit of those searching for answers. They don't have to know exactly what globbing means to know that php curl requires a certain type of format to be adhered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I'm using this and it seems to work

```
$urlReconstructed = str_replace(']', '%5D', str_replace('[', '%5B', $url));
```

Comment: better to call 'str_replace' only once :

`$urlReconstructed = str_replace(array(']', '['), array('%5D', '%5B'), $url);`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($url);    
parse_str($urlParts['query'], $queryParts);
$urlReconstructed = sprintf('%s://%s%s?', $urlParts['scheme'], $urlParts['host'], $urlParts['path']);

foreach ($queryParts as $key => $value)
{
  $urlReconstructed .= $key . "=" . urlencode($value);
}

echo $urlReconstructed;
```

Thanks Pekka, Convert your comment to an answer. If no other better answers pop up i will award you the correct answer.

Comment: Actually this is not the answer. As you can see, the url is already encoded. The only thing it seems that needs encoding are the brackets