# Get json content from a Google Chart url

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to get the json data from the following url:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gv&chl=digraph framework { 1[color=red]; 2; 3[color=red]; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12[color=red]; 13; 14[color=red]; 15; 16[color=red]; 17[color=red]; 2 -> 1; 3 -> 1; 4 -> 1; 5 -> 1; 6 -> 2; 8 -> 9; 9 -> 8; 12 -> 2; 12 -> 3; 12 -> 4; 12 -> 5; 7 -> 6; 7 -> 10; 7 -> 11; 8 -> 7; 13 -> 5; 14 -> 13; 15 -> 6; 16 -> 15; 17 -> 12; 10 -> 4; 11 -> 3; 14 -> 16; 16 -> 17; }&chof=json

I have tried several methods that were suggested in other questions:

```
$jsonurl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gv&chl=digraph framework { 1[color=red]; 2; 3[color=red]; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12[color=red]; 13; 14[color=red]; 15; 16[color=red]; 17[color=red]; 2 -> 1; 3 -> 1; 4 -> 1; 5 -> 1; 6 -> 2; 8 -> 9; 9 -> 8; 12 -> 2; 12 -> 3; 12 -> 4; 12 -> 5; 7 -> 6; 7 -> 10; 7 -> 11; 8 -> 7; 13 -> 5; 14 -> 13; 15 -> 6; 16 -> 15; 17 -> 12; 10 -> 4; 11 -> 3; 14 -> 16; 16 -> 17; }&chof=json"

//Method 1
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl); 
// returns an error from the google page: 400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know

//Method 2
$curlSession = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $jsonurl);
 curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $json_decoded = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
 curl_close($curlSession);
 // returns NULL
 // This makes sense if the JSON isn't not returned correctly. I think json_decode() returns NULL if the input is not correct json data.

 //Method 3
 $json = file_get_contents(urlencode($jsonurl));
 // Gives another error: [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: File name too long
```

If I just post the raw JSON data in my code the rest of my algorithm works fine. The point is, in my actual code the url is dynamic and I need to be able to get the JSON data from the url.

It seems like an security issue with google. However, I don't have a clue as of how to solve this.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. Please let me know if you want to know more/if I should edit my question somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think your JSON URL is what you think it is. Try wrapping it in quotes to start off with, since it contains spaces and semi-colons, which are special characters to PHP.

Comment: Sorry, it's quoted in my original code, that was a typo. What I think the json data is, is that it's some sort of data structure that contains information about the chart/image. If you paste the URL in your browser, it prompts a download which contains the data. All I want to do is contain this data in a variable somehow so I can use `json_decode()` on it and eventually make an image map.

Comment: If you paste that URL into your browser, your browser will convert all the spaces and special characters into %-escaped sequences. Try pasting it into Chrome, then copying the resulting URL out and using that URL instead (it will have no spaces in it). It looks like the brackets will also need to be escaped, which browsers don't normally do. See this answer: [How do I avoid URL globbing with PHP cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137027/how-do-i-avoid-url-globbing-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL needs to be URI-escaped for cURL to use it properly.  If I change your script to this:

```
# note that in this string, all special characters (eg. spaces) are %-escaped
$jsonurl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gv&chl=digraph%20framework%20{%201[color=red];%202;%203[color=red];%204;%205;%206;%207;%208;%209;%2010;%2011;%2012[color=red];%2013;%2014[color=red];%2015;%2016[color=red];%2017[color=red];%202%20-%3E%201;%203%20-%3E%201;%204%20-%3E%201;%205%20-%3E%201;%206%20-%3E%202;%208%20-%3E%209;%209%20-%3E%208;%2012%20-%3E%202;%2012%20-%3E%203;%2012%20-%3E%204;%2012%20-%3E%205;%207%20-%3E%206;%207%20-%3E%2010;%207%20-%3E%2011;%208%20-%3E%207;%2013%20-%3E%205;%2014%20-%3E%2013;%2015%20-%3E%206;%2016%20-%3E%2015;%2017%20-%3E%2012;%2010%20-%3E%204;%2011%20-%3E%203;%2014%20-%3E%2016;%2016%20-%3E%2017;%20}&chof=json";

# your settings here are fine
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $jsonurl);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

# XXX: not entirely safe here
# curl_exec() could dump out something other than JSON if it encounters an error
# I recommend saving the output of curl_exec($c) separately in case of error
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
```

Then `$json` contains the data object I would expect. I tested this in PHP 5.3.15 on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks, that URL works in my code too. Still haven't figured out how to do it myself though. Converting all spaces to %20 and all '>' to %3E doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: See the answer for [url - encodeURI() in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929584/encodeuri-in-php) for a method which will take a given URL and encode it properly.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before. Same error, only thing that works is using google chrome (copy / paste). It's not perfect but I've got it working for some cases now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's odd, it worked for me. I copied the `encodeURI()` function out of that answer, ran the original unencoded `$jsonuri` function through it, and then sent the output through `curl` and got the same result.